# Highchart: Plot negative values on negative Y Axis ans set initial value

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am trying plot area graph with multiple series data. The data consists of negative values as well , but the Y Axis does not plot values below 0. 
[Here](https://codepen.io/bhupendra1011/pen/zYYgzBW) is the codepen for above scenario.

I want to achieve below graph , where Y AXis plots negative values on negative Y Axis and Y Axis should have some start value {which would be first value of sample data}.

[image: highchart]

I tried setting offset for X Axis ,min for Y Axis , but it did not worked out.

```
...
xAxis {
offset:-10000
},
yAXis {
min: 50000
...
```

Kindly let me if the this type of graph can be achieved by HighCharts.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable `yAxis.startOnTick` option, hide the `xAxis` line and use `plotLines` to add the dashed lines:

```
xAxis: {
    ...,

    lineWidth: 0
},
yAxis: {
    ...,

    startOnTick: false,
    plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        dashStyle: 'Dash',
        zIndex: 4
    }]
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kga5f782/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotLines

Comment: Thank you for the reply , but  area graph is not going below X axis , negative Y values are not getting plotted on -ve Y Axis. Graph should get below X Axis to show -ve values as seen in image

Comment: Hi @Bhupendra, Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8gez2cds/

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek , it really solved my issue. Only one doubt - why 3 charts have different starting position (values in Y Axis) , when their first value is same ? I wanted that three charts should have started from one point only , as shown in image above

Comment: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.pointPlacement , point placement works in Column Chart , but here it is Area Chart . Any option available here

Comment: Hi @Bhupendra, That is caused by the `stacking` option. Please check the result without it: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0v7jnar1/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek , thanks for suggesting stacking option. I had filled transparent color for third graph so that third graph does not fill color : http://jsfiddle.net/bg0h6v9n/ .  But after  setting ```stacking:false``` , area below third graph is no more transaparent

Comment: @Bhupendra - It is transparent, but the color is visible from the first series. You can set the `fillColor` as white: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n4e7axvm/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek , I need you help . I have made a prototype : https://codepen.io/bhupendra1011/pen/WNbexzG . I am not able to fix position of  initial amount on Y axis . On click of high/low/medium  , starting position jumps.  Explanation of issue : https://i.ibb.co/YT3g80B/highchart-issue.png.                                      I need to implement behavior like  this graph  : https://www.june.dk/calculator/?investAmount=100.        Kindly let me know . Thanks

Comment: In this graph june.dk/calculator/?investAmount=100. , Y axis always start from same initial value , although graph Y values change on click of different boxes.

Comment: Hi @Bhupendra, You need to set correct value in `plotLines.value` property and `tickPositions`: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4740/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek , thanks a lot , it really worked . Is there any way to disable fill color on hover. color should be filled between top and lowest graph . below lowest graph , I have filled color as white , but on hovering top and second graph , color is highlighted . can it be same as before hovering

Comment: @Bhupendra Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4744/ Is that the result you want to achieve?

Comment: HI @ppotaczek Thanks for replying , I am calculating tickPosition dynamically  => calculating 5 intervals between initial and max value. Updated example : https://codepen.io/bhupendra1011/pen/WNbexzG . When I change graph data by clicking on High of series 2, there is change in position of X axis and gap between X axis dotted line and labels (2020,2021 .. ) increases . Is there any possibility to avoid this . When I toggle graph between HIgh,Low,Medium of Series 1 , it works perfectly , only issues comes when I change to series 2 . Series 2 has 5 values , while series 1 has 20 values

Comment: @Bhupendra, that is because of change in yAxis scale. Can't you keep it consistent?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek  I can't keep Y axis tickPositions as constant . Since the graph chart data can vary because of some user inputs. I am calculating max value  in (High , Low , Medium data for each series ) so that When I toggle between high/low/medium no chart point is left out of range. When I change series (click on series 2) I need to recalculate max value among high/low/medium data

Comment: And that recalculation is causing the change. You need to calculate extremes for both series or keep the same proportion between min and max.

Comment: for recalculating tickPos I am creating tickPos array in equal parts . If I load series 2 first , then also series 2 graph takes large space below xAxis , can be seen on hover  when color gets filled : https://codepen.io/bhupendra1011/full/WNbexzG . In this case before re calculation of tickPos , graph shows large space occupied on hover, as a result labels move down

Comment: there is an option to set Y position of xAxis labels ``` labels: {y:-60} ``` . It's like moving label up by 60px , but then it will cause issue in other scenarios where label position is fine

Comment: @Bhupendra, I did not mean equal parts, but the same proportions between `min` and `max` tick.

Comment: Hi @ ppotaczek, now I am keeping the consistent Y axis tickPos ( taking max value from all series) but now graph does not scale for the series which was much less value compared to max . here is what i get : https://i.ibb.co/kMh5RHc/stackover1.png.   Is there any way to set extremes so that graph does not jump between series1 and series2  :codepen.io/bhupendra1011/full/WNbexzG

Comment: @Bhupendra, You can not change extremes, if you manually calculate `tickPositions`. You have to somehow include it in the tick calculations.